# Running Microsoft Office Communication Server 2007 R2 on virtual machine?

Tags: virtualization, ms-office-communicator

Does anyone know if it is officially supported to run Microsoft Office Communication Server 2007 R2 on a virtual machine? (Virtual PC/VMWare/Hyper-V)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft released a pretty good white paper on it called [Running Microsoft Office Communications Server 2007 R2 in a Virtualized Topology](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0a45d921-3b48-44e4-b42b-19704a2b81b0&displaylang=en). The gist is some roles you can virtualise no problems, but for those Voice, audio/video, Web conferencing, and application sharing roles you need to stick to physical boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost 100% sure it is not supported, and I'm certain it's not recommended. If you look at their "best practices", you'll see they use a ton of servers (10, 15?) for all different roles. Our own implementation is only for 200 users and has 3 servers, one edge server, one cwa and one front server. This was the minimum we had to use for our infrastructure.

I'm sure text would work fine if virtualized, but voice/video would become a problem rather fast I reckon.

Comment: Oh, and VirtualPC is definately out of the question. You REALLY don't want to go down that route.